# PTIJ: Is there any evidence that Tolkien’s Hobbit and Lord of the Rings are based upon the teachings of the Torah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Many of the outer trappings of the popular fantasy novels by [J.R.R Tolkien](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._R._R._Tolkien), *(John Ronald Reuel Tolkien, that Reuel was one of the alternate names of Yitro, Moshe's father-in-law)* [The Hobbit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit) and [The Lord of the Rings trilogy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings) and even his posthumously published [The Silmarillion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silmarillion) appear to have similarities with the teachings of the Torah, like the creation of the universe, the contrast and struggle between light and darkness, good and evil, angelic creatures like the various elves including Galadriel, the elven Queen associated with starlight and the constellations and even shepherd type characters, like Gandalf in comparison to Moses.

Is there any deeper evidence of Torah teaching within the storyline that validates this observation?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: In Soviet Middle Earth, trees eat you!

Comment: VTC comparative religion ;)

Comment: @RabbiKaii Not at all. My suggestion would be that perhaps it is a hidden midrash. Consider Tolkien’s name. Could he be continuing the tradition of Yithro?

Comment: My question would be if it was about Torah, why didn't he just say so, but I think he would just tell me to "shut up" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-Uz0LMbWpI

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jethro_(biblical_figure)#:~:text=In%20the%20Hebrew%20Bible%2C%20Jethro,called%20Reuel%20(or%20Raguel).

Comment: @RabbiKaii In the context of Tolkien's association with one of the alternate names for Yithro, it is important what the Torah records about Yithro prior to the giving of the Torah and his profession. It also should be noted that Yithro was the first convert after the giving of the Torah at Har Sinai. And additionally, that even with Moshe's request that Yithro remain with the Jewish people, Yithro declined and departed to go back to his people in order to correct their mistaken beliefs and to teach them the proper way to serve G-d.

Comment: @RabbiKaii  Also, note the name of the person who assisted Tolkien's son in posthumously publishing the Silmarillion. Another unusual Biblical second name, Gavriel.

Answer (score 5):

The concept of the Hobbit, the archetypal, small underdog, who overcomes all challenges etc. was actually based on Moshe Rabbeinu and him gaining the power of the ring!

Refer to [Shemos 2:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.2.12?vhe=Miqra_Mevoar,_trans._and_edited_by_David_Kokhav,_Jerusalem_2020&lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> **הוא הביט** לכאן ולכאן וראה שאין איש, הוא הרג את המִצרִי וקבר אותו בחול
>
> He (Moshe) was the only Hobbit around here, and he saw that there was no one about, and he killed the Egyptian and buried him in the sand.

Thus, he gained the ring and so his adventures began...

Obviously, Tolkien took some poetic license and created the character Gandalf, but truth be told, this too was based on Moshe who was also a famed wizard (along with Aharon), refer to his staff and his battle with the Egyptian Necromancers [עיין שם](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.7.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

In fact such was Tolkien's audacious show of plagiarism the [Targum Yonasan](https://www.sefaria.org/Targum_Jonathan_on_Exodus.7.12?vhe=Targum_Jonathan_on_Exodus&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) on that very pasuk hints to the authors impending appropriation...

> **וטלקון** אֵינַשׁ חוּטְרֵיהּ וַהֲווֹ לְחָרְמָנִין וּמִן יַד אִתְהֲפִּיכוּ לְמֶהֱוֵי כְּמִן שֵׁירוּיָא וּבְלַע חוּטְרָא דְאַהֲרן יַת חוּטְרֵיהוֹן

Either read it literally i.e. "Each cast down his rod, and they turned into serpents. But Aaron’s rod swallowed their rods." Or rather see b'derech remez:

> And the man Tolkien, will adopt a snake-like (read devious) behaviour. But Aharon's stick (i.e. the genuine Torah-true mehalach) shall swallow that of those fame-seeking pretenders..."

Comment: Can you expand on the subject of the “ring of power”? This needs careful reflection.

Comment: Indeed @YaacovDeane! From the little I know on the subject I believe there are some who posit that this "ring of power" was actually based on Shlomo Hamelech and his adventures with the shedim - ayin sham... (refer to Gittin 68b https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.68b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en amongst other sources)

Comment: There 10 rings made. 3 were given to the elves, and 7 to the dwarves and men. But there was another ring apart, to bind them. One ring to rule them all.

Comment: Are you sure that you would equate the Hobbits, called "the Halvlings" with Moses? (Think in terms of the Half-Shekel we just learned about. That the whole shekel is comprised of 20 gerah, and the Half-Shekel contains 10. What is the extra 10 gerah referring to?) The hint is in the Honorific given to Moshe Rabbeinu, that he is Ish-Elokim, literally "Man-god". Moshe serves as the halachic agent between G-d and the Jewish people, representing both. In that case, the Hobbits would be the Jewish people.

Comment: In the same way Frodo was Hashem's shaliach, so too was Moshe :-)

Comment: Frodo and his Uncle Bilbo both worked with Gandalf. But Gandalf was the key character connecting the whole story together. And like Moshe, Gandalf the Mithrandian (or Myth-randian, meaning the part of the Torah in Bereshit) came from the pre-Middle Earth time in the Silmarillion, pre-Olam HaZeh domain. He was "drawn from the water", so to speak.

Comment: Even relying on your own valuable observation that, "הוא הביט לכאן ולכאן וראה שאין איש", that he (meaning Moshe) is "a Hobbit", the posuk emphasizes that at least at that early stage in his life, when he may have been considered only a Hobbit (equated with a half-shekel), he had not yet become the mature status of, Faithful Shepard when he was also described as Ish-Elokim. Like it says, Moshe looked "to here and to here" and saw  "there was no Ish." He lacked the quality of "Ish" at that time, which he would later acquire to be a "full shekel" of 20 gera, a Holy Shekel.

Answer (score 2):

גנדולף is gematria 173. He who understands, understands.

Comment: מישהו מבין מבין? That phrase isn’t gematria 173. What are you trying to say?

Comment: גל עיני? This phrase is 173.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of אלקים אני יקוה

Comment: And also: אנכי הוי׳ אלקיך

Comment: But to make this gematria comprehensible, because it seems to equate Gandalf, meaning Moshe and G-d, you would need to explicitly point out Shemot 14:31, which says: 
וירא ישראל את היד הגדלה אשר עשה יהוה במצרים וייראו העם את יהוה ויאמינו ביהוה ובמשה עבדו

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> There were 19 rings made. 3 were given to the elves, and 7 to the dwarves
> and 9 were given to men. But there was another ring apart, to bind them. One ring to
> rule them all.

This is the Sefirot. The three rings for the elves are Chochma, Bina and Da'at, the Mochin מוחין. The 7 middot were given to the dwarves and the 9 rings given to men hint to the letter Tet ט, which is like an empty vessel ready to receive. That the 9 is comprised of 3 times 3, alluding to the 3 aspects of the service of all mankind (that שם וחם ויפת, the three sons of Noah, who are the ancestors of all mankind, are comprised of 9 letters), through thought מחשבה, speech דבור and action מעשה, Teshuvah תשובה,  Tefillah תפילה and Tzedakah צדקה, Fasting צום, Voice קול (including the *voice* of the Shofar) and Money ממון.

The 1 ring apart, (the 20th ring) to rule them all is Keter. That the letter Kaf כ is 20 and stands for the Crown כתר of Kingship.

In the books by Tolkien, it is explained that the 20th ring bound the others together and ruled them through the *desire* for gold.

According to Chassidus, Keter is sometimes equated with Ratzon, which can be thought of as *a dictator*, meaning *a determinator* of ultimate expression. Keter is *makif*. But Keter is also associated with *desire* תאוה, that which precedes even the level of will רצון, like is found in the [first chapter of volume one in Sefer HaMa’amarim בשעה שהקדימו by the Rebbe Rashab](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58807&st=&pgnum=9). And this is based upon the teaching from Midrash Tanchuma:

> אָמַר רַבִּי שְׁמוּאֵל בַּר נַחְמָן, בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁבָּרָא **הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא** אֶת הָעוֹלָם, **נִתְאַוָּה** שֶׁיְּהֵא לוֹ דִּירָה בַּתַּחְתּוֹנִים

If considering the expression, *Rings of Power* טבעות פווור, by spelling the word "power" phonetically, it will include the Nekuda of Cholam, which also pertains to what transcends even Keter in the kabbalistic concept of Crowns תגים, Ta'amim טעמים (*also called Trop*), Vowels נקודות, and Letters אותיות. It is represented orthographically with letter "Vav". Similarly, the "W" sound is usually represented with a double "Vav". So the inner letters of the word פווור are 3 "Vavs" or Chai, חי. The word פווור is in small sum, 26, which is represented in prayer as יי. If you look at the small sum of the name represented by יי, meaning יאהדונהי (the name indicating G-d's Kingship), you discover a gematria of 28, כח, which means "*power*". ***Rings of Power!***

Rings are also associated with and compared to *Jewish marriage*, symbolizing the union between husband and wife. A ring has no beginning, no end, no Above and no below. It is also the symbol of the eternal bond between G-d and the Jewish people. That the **No** expressed in all these dimensions actually alludes to the ascending levels of *Bittul*, nullification of the sense of self that makes possible the true union. In the language of Chassidut, this is compared to the moon one instant before the Molad, when it is at its smallest point, ***when there is not even a point of light***. לית לה מגרמא כלום

And like is noted in the answer from @The GRAPKE, "In a private letter, Tolkien explains that ***it was actually impossible to destroy the ring*** because as the ring bearer approached the place of creation of the One Ring, the lust for power would inevitably overwhelm him. It was only the guiding hand of God that pushed Gollum and caused him to fall into the lava flow, causing the destruction of the One Ring."

In this context, it should also be noted that the Giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai is compared to a marriage between HaKadosh, baruch Hu (***the King***) and the Jewish people (***the Queen***). The mountain served as the Chuppah and the Torah was the Ketubah. Moshe was the escort of the King and Aharon was the escort of the Queen (*Kenesset Yisrael*).

Comment: A good beginning but reflect on the rings are called, “Rings of Power”. There are some very profound things in that phrase.

Comment: עשר ספירות בלימה

Comment: טבעות פווור. Spelling the word "power" phonetically, it includes the Nekuda of Cholam, which also pertains to what transcends even Keter. It is represented orthographically with letter "Vav". Similarly, the "W" sound is usually represented with a double "Vav". So the inner letters of the word are 3 "Vavs" or Chai, חי. Consider that word small sum, 26, which is in prayer represented יי.  There  is much more. The subject of "rings" is discussed extensively in connection with marriage and the giving of the Torah. That a ring has no beginning and no end, no Above and no below, etc.

Comment: If you look at the small sum of the name represented by יי, meaning יאהדונהי, you discover a gematria of 28, כח, which means "power". The "Rings of Power"?!

Comment: How about: בלימה means "nothingness". כחמה also means "nothingness" (see Job 28:12). We also know that כחמה means "power" because the Zohar explains it to mean כח מה. Therefore עשר ספירות בלימה means "ten Sefirot of power"

Comment: In Chassidut and according to Sefer Yetzirah, בלימה is understood to mean בלי מהות, without existence. It sounds like a fine distinction, but is referring to that which transcends "letters" altogether. I'm assuming your Job reference is to החכמה מאין תמצא. The Rebbe discusses the subject of the distinctions between אין and אפס extensively and how they relate specifically to ascending levels of "bittul" in the "World of Souls" after one passes from this World, and that which pertains to the "Days of Moshiach" in this world and which transcends even the World of Souls. חכמה originates from אין.

Comment: See the הכל יודוך prayer said after Barchu on Shabbat morning for details.

Comment: "According to Chassidus, Ratzon is a dictator"? What Hebrew word are you translating as "dictator"? מושל? Like in ראש הממשלה? That's the phrase often used to describe the Prime Minister of Israel, the Head or Leader of the sitting government. But I don't think they would appreciate translating it as "Dictator". Would you mind if I collaborate on your answer with an edit?

Comment: @YaacovDeane sure, be my guest! Dictator in the functional sense - it overrules, rather than transforms (taanug) or convinces (sechel to lev) etc

Comment: Thanks. You might want to revisit volume 1, chapter 1 of בשעה שהקדימו by the Rebbe Rashab on the subject of כתר and רצון.

Answer (score 1):

- **I am a servant of the Secret Fire... You
  cannot pass!** : This is a clear reference to the primordial form of the Torah which was written in White Fire on Black Fire.
- **Even the discords of Melkor contributed to the glory of
  creation.** : When the world was created, Melkor, an evil angel, sought to wrest the world to his own purposes. This caused great chaos throughout time, but ultimately resulted in a greater glory of creation than would have been possible without Melkor's dischords. This is a clear reference to the idea that by overcoming the *yetzer ha'ra* we achieve a greater *kavod shamayim* than would have been possible had we not have had *bechirah*.
- **The destruction of the One Ring:** In a private letter, Tolkien explains that it was actually impossible to destroy the ring because as the ring bearer approached the place of creation of the One Ring, the lust for power would inevitably overwhelm him. It was only the guiding hand of God that pushed Gollum and caused him to fall into the lava flow, causing the destruction of the One Ring. This is a clear reference to (Kiddushin 30b) "ואמר ר"ש בן לוי יצרו של אדם מתגבר עליו בכל יום ומבקש המיתו שנאמר צופה רשע לצדיק ומבקש להמיתו ואלמלא הקב"ה עוזרו אין יכול לו"

Comment: Ok, but that's not even Purim Torah, except for #1 ;)

Comment: Welcome aboard @TheGRAPKE. The subject of the rings and Gandalf are what relate specifically to "Purim Torah".

Comment: @YaacovDeane But we need to understand the context in which the One Ring and Gandalf operate?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE No argument there. But a clear distinction that "the Secret Fire" and the "place of creation" are talking about "the Tzimtzum HaRishon" and what precedes that, should be mentioned. If you're enjoying this, you should look through the comments for both Dov and RabbiKaii. There really is quite a bit being discussed. The disclaimer: "not intended to be taken completely seriously" should emphasize "completely"! "In jest" does not have to mean "inane".

Comment: @YaacovDeane It's not inane, I object to your comment.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I'm not talking about your answer. I'm referring to my original question. Do you see the giant sized disclaimer that appears with every PTIJ question? https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated

Comment: @YaacovDeane Your response was inappropriate.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE If I caused you any hurt or embarrassment, I apologize. I assure you that my comment was not directed or intended about your answer in any way. My comment about "inane" was only meant to clarify how I am understanding the "In jest" aspect of the tag phrase, "Purim-Torah-In-Jest". I was actually validating your answer from the critique that it received from AKA in the first comment (that only bullet-point 1  qualified as "Purim Torah"). Meaning the rest of your answer would be invalid for consideration. "In jest", meaning light-hearted and merry. "Inane" meaning insigifiganct, empty.