# What is the definition of "will" in Judaism?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, sefirot-attributes

I am trying to understand Keter (crown) from the Sefirot, and it keeps talking about "G-d's **Will**". But no formal or mathematical definition is given of ["will"](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1761308/jewish/Will.htm). I am looking for something more detailed, perhaps formal/mathematical, or perhaps just deriving will from more primitive notions/elements.

For example, when I thought deeply about will several years ago, asking myself where does my will come from, and things like that, I came up with the idea of "urges". Urges come first, and we read these urges and make decisions from them based on our knowledge and experience, sort of thing. Will is the sum total of how we act on urges, so will really isn't tangible like urges are.

But the urges, where do they come from? They seem to "arise" out of thin air, but that isn't much of a description. Instead, I imagined that the urges were sent, like signs in the darkness, kites in the night sky. The urges are sent notes so to speak, on which direction we should move (i.e. which decision we should prefer in our current network of decisions we need to make). This, if nothing else, provides a deeper look (however right or wrong) at the idea of "will", where it comes from, and how it is structured.

So in that sense, what is divine will? Where does it come from? Why does it come about? And what is its inner structure?

Saying that G-d has will is taking a lot of assumptions for granted, and wondering if will can be derived from other things somehow. Or else how it can otherwise be explained. Not talking about free will but will in general, and specifically also divine will.

Comment: Have you ever studied Chassidut? This is the exact kind of question it deals with at length. If you want to see it dealt with in a more formal, logical/philosophical way, then Chabad Chassidut is what I recommend. Moreh Nevuchim also has sections on the philosophy of Hashem's will. Note, mathematics is within the realm of reason, and will is beyond reason, so I wonder if mathematics can be applicable at all, however there are some mathematical-like statements that exist to help understand it

Comment: "In the Idra of Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai, it was taught: 'When the primordial will desires to establish the highest holiness, the holy of holies, it did not establish it through regular corrections, as the upper and lower worlds did not establish rectifications and improvements, but rather remained in their original state. And this is the language of the Ramban in his commentary on Sefer Yetzirah (Formation Book), where he states that the existence of all things is sustained by the divine will in them, meaning that the existence of the lower and upper worlds is dependent on the extension of

Comment: of emanation of the highest holiness within them, and everything will be when the will is turned to its source, as it attracts all existence to it.'"

Thus, Rabbi Shimon bar Yochai explains that the existence of the worlds is the extension of emanation from the highest holiness that is the heart and will, and without it, existence and its sustenance would be impossible. Therefore, it were absolutely necessary and incumbent upon the extension of emanation from the unique Master to be revealed after it was concealed within it, in order to establish all existing things and reveal His existence.

Comment: ^ From Avodat Hakodesh by ibn Gabbai, Chelek 1 Chapter 8, see more there https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Avodat_Hakodesh/1

Comment: In keeping with the season, there is actually a very good explanation with some links at this Purim Torah answer. The section you will want to look at is about the 20th ring of power, the one to bind them, one ring to rule them all. If it is helpful, don’t forget to give it an upvote. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/141160/7303

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The philosophy of will is a Kabbalistic matter, and the deep definitions and philosophical treatment of this topic you are looking for is found in Chabad Chassidut. There is an immense amount of treatment of the topic by the Rebbeim over 300 years and hundreds of *maamarim* and *sichot*.

---

Headers on the topic:

- Keter is the most esoteric, simple and primordial of the Sefirot, i.e. modes of expression.
- This is the beginning of all activity in the soul - the interface between activity and essence, between the person themself and their expressions.
- The structure of Keter is generally broken down, like all of the Sefirot, into an "external/superficial" (will) and "internal/personal" (*taanug*/delight)
- The structure of Ratzon itself is higher and lower. The lower Ratzon arises from the intellect, in the sense one desires that which he has studied, and is limited. The higher arises from the essence of the soul itself.
- Will is considered *makif*, i.e. it surrounds a person from without. One meaning of this is that a person doesn't consider themself in conscious control of their will; it is subconscious. Another meaning is that will doesn't have a "faculty" or "organ", it is the general expression of the soul itself.
- The Divine soul, and Divine Will, are different from the animal, in the same way all Divine expressions are different. The Divine is the Nimshal, and the animal is the mashal. The Divine is beyond comprehension and reason (and "mathematics"), but we can access it through studying the animal.
- The ideal state and refinement of the Ratzon of animal soul is to act similar to the Divine soul, i.e. authentic desire; desire for what is deep, true and holy. Desire for others rather than the material, in service of others, rather than the self.
- Keter encompasses all the other Serfirot; it is general, and the rest are specific. Chessed is general Ratzon/Taanug, in a specific mode of giving and closeness. Gevura is it in the mode for restriction and justice etc.
- Ratzon is a dictator, in that it overrules the intellect and emotions if necessary to get on board with pursuing the object of the desire.

If the above doesn't highlight how complicated and potentially confusing the topic is, then I don't know what will. It is such a difficult subject to talk about, and yet there is so much to talk about, and so many layers and levels and perspectives to deal with separately, and then integrate, and is indeed a lifetime's study.

[Here is a lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1v-Cf8gcRM) that will answer the following questions, but in summary:

##### Where does Divine will come from?

The concept of desire has an interesting discussion - what causes the desire? Does the object of the desire sell itself to us and convince us to want it when we see it, or do we essentially want it; does the desire reflect/express who we fundamentally are, in our selves? Does the desire arise from without or within?

Hashem Himself is not externally influenced at all, so His Will arises *from Himself*; it's Him i.e. an absolutely authentic expression of Himself - in fact the Rambam states in Moreh Nevuchim that Hashem's Will and His Essence are identical. Divine will is the need to be thoroughly oneself, in every way.

This idea is considered beyond understanding, but we can get a feel for it as we study these topics.

##### Why does it come about?

It does not come about. Hashem never changes. Hashem wanting Oneness is an absolute statement. You can't ask why He wants this intimacy with us, because that would imply that there is a higher reason, or an end result that this intimacy leads to, and the question will start over. That's incorrect, intimacy with us *is* what He wants, and that's **everything** we know about Who He is.

In this sense, it should be noted that the word רצון is also the letters that constitute צנור which means tube, pipe or conduit. This concept connects with the sixth of the Middot, the Sefirah of Yesod and Yosef ***HaTzaddik***. That Yesod is the conduit or point of connection and union, the organ of reproduction. And it also forms the word נוצר, as in נוצר חסד לאלפים, the seventh of the 13 attributes of mercy (see Shemot 34:6-7). That the seventh of the Middot is the Sefirah of Malchut, which is associated with David. And in this context, the level of Will רצון is the unification of Yosef צנור and David נוצר to be one, Keter-Malchut כתר-מלכות, like is found in the Haftorah to parshat VaYigash from [Yechezkel 37:15-28](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.37.15?lang=bi).

---

##### Sources

Deep thinkers are urged by our sages to study the deep works they provided for us, because deep thinkers are able to and it is incumbent on them to reach their potential in understanding, but also there's a 99% chance they will get it wrong if they do it by themselves (see the introduction of Chovot Halevavot)

It is hard to provide a neat list of sources because, as I am trying to stress, this is a huge topic, and is covered in many different places. I have said that Chabad Chassidut is the most contemporary, deep and thorough treatment of the subject, so my recommendation is to start with Tanya, and find a Chabad Rav whose class you can join. From there, you will be able to gradually navigate through the *maamarim* and *sichot* that cover Ratzon, Ta'anug, Ta'avah, the Sefirot, the Divine soul and Animal soul, concepts of *makif* and *penimi*, different levels of relationships, and much more. It is important go through the preliminary topics, in order, and proceed methodically and patiently.

The *ma'amarim* of the Frierdiker Rebbe (Rayatz) in Sefer Ma'arim 5691 and [Chassidic Discourses](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/82895/jewish/Chassidic-Discourses.htm) come to mind as strong recommendations. The series of *ma'amarim* called [בשעה שהקדימו](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58807&st=&pgnum=9) are very relevant to your specific questions on Divine will.

The best contemporary explainer of Ratzon I've personally come across is Rabbi Manis Friedman, who has thousands of lectures online, most of which are very connected to this topic. He is very easy to listen to, and good at "talking around" this esoteric *inyan* until you "fall in" and comprehend it. The series "Get To Know Yourself" would be a good idea, specifically [part 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-8vaUuDI3s) "Motivators: Reason, Will and Pleasure", [part 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VDth3P3hus) "High: Nothing Stronger Than Will" and [part 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jA-SVqZXag) "Higher: Nothing Higher Than Pleasure".

I would also recommend studying Moreh Nevuchim, especially the Chapters in part 1 from 52 onwards, and Part 3, to understand the philosophy of Hashem's Essence, and expression, and where Ratzon fits into that, and how to correctly understand it.

Comment: I'm surprised Chabad agrees with learning Moreh Nevuchim. Generally speaking, Kabbalists are exceedingly anti any sifrei chakirah because they fly in the face of Kabbalah, and Moreh Nevuchim stands out as the archetype. Examples include the Leshem Shevo V'achlamah and Rebbe Nachman miBreslov.

Comment: @Yehuda That is its own discussion, but to be clear, I am not a Lubavitcher.